# Changing dynamic text using jQuery in code from Adobe Animate

Tags: jquery, html, adobe

Welcome to Adobe Animate, I created animations which is in the HTML file 5. I start animations from the button that performs the startup functions:

I create animations in adobe animate

in one file:

```
function start() {
        exportRoot.gotoAndPlay();
        'This is the text you want to get';     <-- How to do it here? How to appeal?
}
```

in two file

```
this.name = new cjs.Text("This text wants to change", "38px 'Geometr415 Blk BT'", "#282828");
    this.name.name = "name";
    this.name.textAlign = "center";
    this.name.lineHeight = 53;
    this.name.lineWidth = 444;
    this.name.alpha = 0.00000000;
    this.name.parent = this;
    this.name.setTransform(348.4,779.75);
```

I would like to edit this text using a button that calls functions to html and in html from adobe and refers to this js from adobe where it changes text